# Stream ReadAsync/WriteAsync in Framework 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, async-await, vimeo-api

```
private async Task<byte[]> ReadDataStream(long totalLength)
{
    var buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int read = 0;
    int totalRead = 0;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while (totalRead < totalLength)
        {
            read = await Data.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            totalRead += read;
            await ms.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Trying to read stream data using ReadAsync but it say's doesn't support in framework 4.0, is there other alternate way to read stream async

Error:

```
Error   2   'System.IO.Stream' does not contain a definition for 'ReadAsync' and no extension method 'ReadAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.Stream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\vimeo-dot-net\src\VimeoDotNet\Net\BinaryContent.cs   130 39  VimeoDotNet
Error   3   'System.IO.MemoryStream' does not contain a definition for 'WriteAsync' and no extension method 'WriteAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\vimeo-dot-net\src\VimeoDotNet\Net\BinaryContent.cs   132 30  VimeoDotNet
```

Comment: This code compiles fine on .NET 4.0 with `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` installed. Did you try to clean and re-build?

Answer (score 2):

Using Yuval's suggestion worked.

In the package manager console type the following:

> Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async